# Extracting files from RAR archive

Tags: c#, winrar

I am trying  to extract files from Rar But i Get message

> "Cannot use Archive random access on SOLID Rar files"

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Luka\Desktop\RarFiles\", "*.rar",
                                    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);


foreach (var item in filePaths)
{
    var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(item);//@"C:\test.rar"Monitoring

    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries.Where(x=> x.Key.Contains("Monitoring")))
    {
        if (!entry.IsDirectory)
        {
            entry.WriteToDirectory(@"D:\WinrarrFiles");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your interpretation of the error

Comment: ["Solid"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression) means that all source files have been bundled and then compressed as one "blob". Apparantly `ArchiveFactory` does not know how to handle that. Or maybe it can extract the entire archive (all files) at once, but maybe even not that.

Comment: Is there any other possible ways ? I want to open Text File from Rar and then work on that file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [tutorial](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/wiki/API-Examples), this is the right way to read the rar.

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Code\sharpcompress.rar"))
{
    var reader = ReaderFactory.Open(stream);
    while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
    {
        if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
        {
            reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(@"C:\temp", new ExtractionOptions() { ExtractFullPath = true, Overwrite = true });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want To get specific file reader.Entry.Key.Contains("Monitoring") i dont really want to use while here cause i will have many RARS and in rar is many files.

Comment: @lukacecxladze seem like ArchiveFactory doesn't work with rar. I don't think you have the choice...

Comment: is there a way not to Extract but To open that file ? in winrar i have Text Files . Can I Open that text file without extracting it out ?

Comment: @lukacecxladze try to test it. I think you can't

Comment: can i at list rename the file ? which i extract ?